# Having trouble passing model into Controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems passing my model into a Controller method.  I'm hoping someone can help.

Here's the model (as requested):

```
public IEnumerable<StatsForPieChart> statsForPieChart { get; set; }

public class StatsForPieChart
{
    public string destAgency { get; set; }
    public long recordCount { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I have a partial view entitled "_Report.cshmtl".  Within this partial view, I have utilized a function's return to create a table of data and now I want to use that same data (without executing an additional function call) to display a pie chart.  Within the partial view, I do the following:

```
@Url.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", Model.statsForPieChart)
```

I have already confirmed via a break at this line, that the statsForPieChart Inumerable is correctly populated with the data that I need.  The controller method looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult PieChartReport(dbModels.AgencyViewModel.statsForPieChart _statsForPieChart)
```

When I break on line one of the controller method, the method is aware that the _statsForPieChart is a reference to the Model, but the value is now NULL.  I've lost all the data.

I'm certain it's something simple, but I have yet to find a solution.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Additional input based on attempts to utilize suggestions below:
1. I attempted using the following, but the value remained NULL:

```
@Html.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", new { _statsForPieChart = Model.statsForPieChart })
```

2. I attempted using the following with form tags, but the value remained NULL:

   ```
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.statsForPieChart)
   @Html.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", new { _statsForPieChart = Model.statsForPieChart })
   ```
3. I attempted using the following form call and the method was never called:

   @using (Html.BeginForm("PieChartReport", "Agency"))
   {
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => mode.startsForPieChart)
   }

Comment: show your model definition

Comment: use a form and you will need to create hidden field for each property in model to post all the value to controller

Comment: I attempted a form in two different ways without success.

Comment: `@Html.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", Model.statsForPieChart)` (`Action(), not `Url()`)and you cannot use `HiddenFor()` to generate values for a complex object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong helper method. **[`Url.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)** is used to generate url for particular action and controller passed as input, i believe you need `Html.Action` in this case as you want to render the partial view as a result of this call,and note that the parameter passed to **[`Html.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object))** should match the name with the parameter you have in the action method, otherwise it will not be posted back.

so change this:

```
@Url.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", Model.statsForPieChart)
```

to this:

```
@Html.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", new {_statsForPieChart= Model.statsForPieChart })
```

Comment: I attempted this modification, but the value remained NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully pass the data using a recommendation above.  The final solution, looks as follows:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("PieChartReport", "Agency", new { model = Model })" />
```

I still don't know why it originally returned NULL, but it's working now.